# Rails messing up with HTTP POST Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, parameters

Our app provides an API that people can use to submit URLs like this:

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/resource -d'url=http://news.google.com/newshl=en&q=obama&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss'
```

Unfortunately, it seems that Rails messes up with this param. Any idea on how to fix this?
See the log below :

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-06-08 19:03:09) [POST]
  Parameters: {"um"=>"1", "url"=>"http://news.google.com/newshl=en", "output"=>"rss", "q"=>"obama", "ie"=>"UTF-8"}
```

I would expect the following :

```
  Parameters: {"url"=>"hhttp://news.google.com/newshl=en&q=obama&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss"}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the behavior you were expecting?  (Do you want `url` to be the whole new.google.com URL?)

Comment: yes, exactly, I would expect a param "url" like "http://news.google.com/newshl=en&q=obama&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly Rails messes up?

If you are referring to the fact that it didn't get complete Google URL (i.e. separated it to output, q and other params) that's because you need to encode '&' character if you want to use it as a part of a value. Something like:

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/resource -d'url=http://news.google.com/newshl=en%26q=obama%26um=1%26ie=UTF-8%26output=rss'
```

Comment: the problem is that we have several other params, that are not in the url param. How can I make the difference between them?

Comment: Where do you have more params?

Comment: In the POST query, thre is more than just the POST, and I can't really make the difference between the POST params and the query string params of the url param.

Comment: You can. If you replace & with %26 in the url param it will be treated as one param. Then you just add additional params after it by using &. Something like this: curl -X POST http://app.local/resource -d'url=http://news.google.com/newshl=en%26q=obama%26um=1%26ie=UTF-8%26output=rss&additional_param=1'